# Как вставить имя пользователя в url адрес на django?

Tags: python, django, url

Я использую django с django-allauth. Я сделал шаблон профиля, адрес которого -
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/. логично, что это неправильно и адрес на профиль должен быть таким [http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/{user.name}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/%7Buser.name%7D)

А смог это сделать с помощью адаптера
adapter.py

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter


class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    template_name = 'registration/profile.html'

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        path = "/profile/{username}/"
        return path.format(username=request.user.username)
```

При входе я перенаправляюсь на страницу, но она не найдена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

может мне нужно как-то отобразить шаблон или отобразить адаптер в url?

помогите, пожалуйста.